# Express JS set a cookie doesn't work when using res.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I have a `login` route where I want to set a cookie after I verify the login credentials. **The client and the server are on different ports**.

```
const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: true,
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/login', (req, res) => {

  res.cookie('secureCookie', JSON.stringify({ id: 1 }), {
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: true,
  });

  return res.json({ success: true });
});

app.use('/check', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.cookies);

  return res.json({ id: 1 });
});
```

The issue is that I don't see the cookie in the devtools (applications tab) after the login request returns. Also, when trying to fetch the `check` endpoint using `credentials: 'include'` it doesn't send the cookie.

What I'm doing wrong?

Here are the requests:

```
  fetch('http://localhost:4000/login');

  fetch('http://localhost:4000/check', {
    credentials: 'include',
  });
```

Comment: *I don't see the cookie in the devtools* -  in the console or in the application tab?

Comment: in the application tab

Comment: How do you make the request?

Comment: You have to add `credentials` to the first call as well

Comment: You're welcome to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Using Fetch article on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

> Unless fetch() is called with the credentials option set to include, fetch():
>
> - won't send cookies in cross-origin requests
> - won't set any cookies sent back in cross-origin responses

`credentials: include` must be set for requests to make them save cookies

Answer (score -2):

just delete return

```
res.json({ success: true });
```